# Java programs wont run in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, java

I have downloaded the java jdk in the terminal window of Ubunutu.  I am trying to trace the number of system calls a No-op java program runs for my computer science class.  the program looks like so:

```
/* Java No-op program */

public class Noop {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.exit(0);
  }
}
```

very simple.

It compiles using javac Noop.java and then in my directory, I get a Noop.class file.  But when I try java Noop to run the program I get this error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:
>   Noop : Unsopported major.minor version 51.0   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:634)   at
>   java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:
>   142)   at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
>   at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:73)   at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:212)   at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   java.net.ClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)   at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)   at
>   Java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
>   could not find the main class: Noop. Program will exit.

I have tried running other java programs that I know work, and same result.

Please Help.

Comment: Is your JRE(Java Runtime Environment) up to date?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like your `java` doesn't match your `javac`. What output do you get from running `java -version` and `javac -version`?

Comment: Yeah when I did that it said my java compiler is 1.0.7_147 but my java is just 1.6.0_23.  How do I fix this/update my java?

Comment: That's a really strange version of javac. What do you get from running `type java` and `type javac`? Although to make a long story short, if it's practical, I think the most expedient solution (and simplest to explain) is just to download the JDK straight from [Sun/Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).